# can't close recordset in asp&sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I keep getting this error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
>   Operation is not allowed when the
>   object is closed.

The Asp code i'm using:

```
    rs.open "usp_reply_insert 132 ,N'abc',N'teeeeeeext',0,N'gest','x@x.com' ",conn
    rs.close
```

The problem is with the rs.close command

This is the Stored Procedure

```
    ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_reply_insert]
    @maamar_id int,
    @subject nvarchar(200),
    @text nvarchar(max),
    @userid int,
    @name nvarchar(50),
    @email nvarchar(150)
    AS
    begin

    set nocount on

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_reply
      (maamar_id,
      userid,
      reply_subject,
      reply_text,
      reply_name,
      reply_email,
      reply_date,
      reply_status
      )
VALUES
      (
      @maamar_id,
      @userid,
      @subject,
      @text,
      @name,
      @email,
      getdate(),
      0
      )



    end
```

How can I close this recored set?

10x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation on the [Recordset.Open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> It is not a good idea to use the
>   Source argument of the Open  method to
>   perform an action query that does not
>   return records because there is no
>   easy way to determine whether the call
>   succeeded. The Recordset  returned by
>   such a query will be closed.
>
> To
>   perform a query that does not return
>   records, such as a SQL INSERT
>   statement, call the Execute method of
>   a Command object or the Execute method
>   of a Connection object instead.

In short, your rs.open call is not resulting in an open recordset, so the `rs.close` statement doesn't function and should be removed. Better yet, follow the example given in the quoted text, as using ADODB.Recordset to invoke an INSERT op is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Your `recordset` is closed, that's why `rs.close` method doesn't work.
You can use that simple code below to check if a recordset is open or closed (if `state=1` it's open, else if `state=0` it's closed)

```
Dim state As Long
state = rs.state
If state <> 0 Then
rs.close
set rs = Nothing
End If
```